# Configure integration of SharePoint Online in the azure active directory

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure-ad, sso, saml

I need you help please!

I want to integrate SharePoint online in the azure active directory and apply SSO (single_sign_on).

I follow this tutorial: [Configure Azure AD single sign-on](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/sharepoint-on-premises-tutorial#configure-azure-ad-single-sign-on)

But I arrive at this step where I do not know what I should put instead of `"urn: <sharepointFarmName>: <federationName>"`

[image]

Comment: I believe this article is for SharePoint on-premises and not for SharePoint online.

Comment: did you have another solution ?

Comment: Im really confused that article is for sharepoint on premise version. SSO should be already working for share-point online.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sso), Seamless SSO needs the user's device to be domain-joined only, but it is not used on Azure AD Joined or Hybrid Azure AD joined devices.

SSO on Azure AD joined, Hybrid Azure AD joined, and Azure AD registered devices works based on the [primary refresh token](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/concept-primary-refresh-token).